# What EXIF tags does Google Photos use for GPS?

Tags: google-photos, gps

A long time ago I took pictures on a trip, and also collected GPS positions. I wrote a script that uses `exiftool` to set the GPS metadata on the pictures, e.g.

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -exif:gpslatitude=25.698618 -exif:gpslongitude=32.640064 -xmp:gpslatitude=25.698618 -xmp:gpslongitude=32.640064 dscf2495.jpg
```

I can see the correct latitude and longitude in the Details tab of the Windows file info. However, when I upload it to Google Photos, the Info tab doesn't show the geolocation (map and pin) that it shows for pictures from my phone, for example.

Any idea what EXIF tags does Google Photos look at to determine geolocation? I have the feeling I'm missing something silly, like a GPS version or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - it's GPSLatitudeRef and GPSLongitudeRef.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense. Those two fields only indicate the hemisphere (N/S and E/W). There must be more to it.

Comment: I see now that you meant you need those two fields in addition to GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude. With all 4 fields, Google Photos is now recognizing locations.Thanks for the pointer!